# if $f(x,y)$ vanish on the point $(a,b)$ then $(f(x,y))\subset (x-a,y-b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, commutative-algebra

Let $f(x,y)\in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ be a irreducible polynomial , assume that $f(a,b) = 0$ prove that $(f(x,y)) \subset (x-a,y-b)$. and the inclusion is strict.

---

Sorry I know nothing about the polynomial with several variables, I try to apply division algorithm but it seems that division algorithm do not hold for multivariable case?

Comment: You may think of $f(x,y)$ as a polynomial in $\mathbb C[x][y]$, ie. a polynomial in one variable $y$ over the ring of polynomials in $x$. Since $\mathbb C[x]$ is an Euclidean domain, you can perform the division algorithm there.

Comment: Yeah thank you I found the similar idea in Vakil's book, and trying to do it in this way @Suzet

Comment: All right! Let us know if your attempt is successful :)

Comment: Hi @Suzet, I found an alternative approach, we know $ev_{(a,b)}: \Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x-a,y-b) \to \Bbb{C}$ that maps $\bar{f} \mapsto f(a,b)$ is isomorphism, and we know $\Bbb{C}[x,y] \to \Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x-a,y-b)\to \Bbb{C}$ maps $f(x,y)$ in the post to $0$ therefore $f\mapsto \bar{f} = 0 \in \Bbb{C}[x,y]/(x-a,y-b)$ so $f\in (x-a,y-b)$ therefore $(f) \subset (x-a,y-b)$?

Comment: Well, when stating that $\mathbb C[x,y]/(x-a,y-b) \xrightarrow{\sim} \mathbb C$ is an isomorphism, you are implying that the kernel of the ring homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb C[x,y] \rightarrow \mathbb C$, sending $f$ to $f(a,b)$, is the ideal $(x-a,y-b)$. But isn't it precisely what you are trying to prove in the first place? I mean, the first part of your question is precisely to prove $\mathrm{Ker}(\varphi) \subset (x-a,y-b)$.

Comment: Oh you are right, I will write down the correct proof later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the Suzet's comment, we can use division algorithm on $f(x,y) \in \Bbb{C}[x][y]$ therefore exist some $g(x,y) \in \Bbb{C}[x][y]$ and $r\in \Bbb{C}[x]$ such that :

$$f(x,y) = g(x,y)(y-b) + r(x)$$

since $f(a,b) = 0$ we have $r(a) = 0$ then we can apply the division theorem over $\Bbb{C}[x]$ so that $r(x) = (x-a) t(x)$ which shows $f(x,y) \in ((y-b),(x-a))$

Comment: Perfect ! It remains to see why the inclusion $(f) \subset (x - a, y - b)$ is strict

Comment: thank you Suzet , That's because $(f)$ is principal, while all the maximal ideal is of the form $(x-a,y-b)$ which is not principal.